# Accessing object elements in list

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, flask, response

I get the response of a server:

```
r = requests.get(my_url)
print(r.text)
json_response = json.loads(r.text)
print(type(json_response))
```

I am using `json.loads()` to convert the string into json. However, the response has this format:

```
[{"element_info":{"data":201863539001,......]
```

I want to access `element_info.data`. I tried accessing it with `json_response.element_info.data` but i got `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'bkdn_elem_info'`.

I also tried `content = r.read()` and i got `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'`.

Comment: ``json_response[0]["element_info"]["data"]``

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this worked! Make a proper answer so you get the points. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access the elements of a dictionary in python with '.' operator as in javascript. You have to use the square bracket notation as below to access the elements

```
json_response[0]["element_info"]["data"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of `json_response` is `list`. So, you can iterate on it and access each element in it. Each element is a dictionary. So, you can use the keys:

```
for each_element in json_response:
    print(each_element["element_info"]["data"])
```

If you are not sure that these keys are available in all elements, you can use the `get()` method with a default value to avoid errors when the key does not exist. Here, the first operand is the key that you want to read, and the second operand can be used to define a default value:

```
for each_element in json_response:
    print(each_element.get("element_info", {}).get("data", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

In access to data from a list, you must specify the element with index first and then get the property of the object

```js
objectOfList =json_response[0];

value  = objectOfList["element_info"]["data"];
```